# How do I get my function to output only true case for conditions on its arguments

Tags: core-language, conditional

I am quite new to Mathematica and have an issue regarding **which** statement.

```
cut[x_, y_] := which[x>y, doFunctionX[], y>x, doFunctionY[]]
cut/@{X,Y}]
```

I wish to display only the **true** case. However, I am unable to find an operation to do it.

Comment: NOt really sure what you're trying to do with the last line, since `X` and `Y` are not numbers (and it should be `cut[X, Y]` anyway). But, if you change `which` to `Which` (all built-in functions in *Mathematica* are capitalized), your code should be fine. When you change that, `cut[5, 3]` evaluates to `doFunctionX[]`.

Comment: Here is a good post with common pitfalls for new users. I anchored it to your issue (Mathematica is case sensitive and the built-in system functions always start with a capital letter): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395

Comment: You may also want to consider handling the case when `x == y`.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was due to not capitalizing the first letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica you can do this with function name overloading. Like so:

```
cut[x_, y_] /; x > y := doFunctionX[]
cut[x_, y_] /; x < y := doFunctionY[]
```

where the [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (/;) operator enforces the conditions you want to place on the arguments.